# Can my facebook app serve a gallery from a different facebook account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to serve a Facebook gallery for a client, and due to the server the site is being hosted on, the request needs to be authenticated.

I have set up an app using our company Facebook developer account. Although I have set the domain of the app to that of our client's, the gallery returned in the request is empty.

I am assuming that I will need access to the client's facebook account so I can create an app associated directly with their facebook account - the one where I want the galleries from? EDIT - just thought I'd point out that the client would prefer not to give me their passwords for their facebook account...

Here is the auth code I have used, if anyone will be kind enough to point out any school boy errors I may have made.

```
$no_albums = 6;
$latest_albums = null;

$user_id = "xxxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$app_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                        . "client_id=" . $user_id
                        . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret 
                        . "&grant_type=client_credentials"
                    . "&scope=user_photos";

$response = wp_remote_get($app_token_url);
$access_token = $response['body'];
error_log(print_r($response,true));

$query = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user_id.'/albums?' . $access_token;
$albums = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$user_id.'/albums') );
```

And this is the response I get ( $albums ) in my error logs:

```
Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [access-control-allow-origin] => *
            [cache-control] => private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
            [content-type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
            [etag] => "1050253aec7b29caff644806927dabfa81406eee"
            [expires] => Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
            [pragma] => no-cache
            [x-fb-rev] => 812093
            [x-fb-debug] => 9I0lRzV3GZxrflP/19iBvhly6FLUVI9jCHJAXcw0Dm0=
            [date] => Mon, 13 May 2013 10:45:39 GMT
            [connection] => close
            [content-length] => 11
        )

    [body] => {"data":[]}
    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
            [message] => OK
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

    [filename] =>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of basic problems here.

First, in your API request, you are looking for albums associated with your `APP_ID`. There are none. You should be using the client's `PAGE_ID` or `USER_ID` in the request to the graph API.

Second, you should be using the Facebook [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) instead of `file_get_contents()` to make your requests. Especially if this is to be a production environment.

If your clients albums are publicly visible, you may not need to authenticate a user to view them. To know this for sure, you'd need to share your client's Facebook username.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just checked and what I have as $app_id as above is the client's USER_ID- bad form on my part. I've updated the variable name. The client's albums are visible, as I am serving them from another server without authentication ( there are reasons why we serve different parts of the site from different servers ) - so authentication is required. As for the SDK - apart from this being the accepted way of doing things from facebook's point of view, is it likely that using the SDK would solve the issue, or is this just highlighted as best practice?

Comment: The SDK is a best practice. You won't get help here for trying to reinvent the wheel when there is a perfectly good wheel already available.

Comment: You've still got a lot of other issues with your code. Including `APP_ID` and `USER_ID` are different, you can't authenticate using a non-interactive `wp_remote_get()` call, and your `access_token` (if you have one) isn't being used anyway.